# Is caching in ASP.NET shared across users or specific to an individual?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have a quick question I'm just not sure about. I'm trying to increase performance on an intranet site. I'm trying to limit the trips to the database by implementing some caching. I'm new to caching and I wasn't sure is this shared across users? I'm hoping it's unique to the individual user. Like every user would have their own independent cache much like the session object. I'm trying things like this

```
   if (Cache["_InfoResult"] == null)
        {
            Cache["_InfoResult"] = db.GetInfoResultBySessionGuid(SessionGuid);
        }

        _InfoResult = (InfoResult)Cache["_InfoResult"];
```

and then using the _InfoResult object to drive areas of the page. My concern was that I want Cache["_InfoResult"] to be unique for each user. Is this correct or would this object be the same for each user? Thanks for clearing it up.

Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 13):

The ASP.Net [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) is attached to the application domain, so it's shared for all users.

If you want to cache something for an individual user, use the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate%28VS.80%29.aspx) object.

Comment: ASP .Net Cache is supposed to be used for things which require extensive server resources but they are shared across users. Is there any feature in ASP .Net or a concept in general in web world where the access is user specific and it also allows you to store very resource intensive objects. Or is it okay if I store some very very heavy objects which are user specific in session itself?

Answer (score 3):

The cache has a global scope and it persists for the lifetime of your web application. **It is not per httprequest.**

You can test this with some simple code.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtData" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnPutToCache" runat="server" Text="Put to Cache" onclick="btnPutToCache_Click" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnGetFromCache" runat="server" text="Get from Cache" onclick="btnGetFromCache_Click" />
<br />
<asp:Label id="lblGetFromCache" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

And the codebehind:

```
protected void btnPutToCache_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Cache["data"] = txtData.Text;
    }
    protected void btnGetFromCache_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        lblGetFromCache.Text = Cache["data"].ToString();
    }
```

Put all of the above code into one page. Deploy your website. Hit the page from instance of your browser window, put some test text into the text box and hit the Put to Cache button.

Open a new browser window and hit the page. Click the Get from Cache button, and observe the results.